# Problem opening pattern file in photoshop cs5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

Pattern:

[image: Sample image]

[Link to pattern](http://dribbble.com/shots/309273-20-Vintage-Photoshop-Patterns?list=following&page=1).

I downloaded this pattern from the internet but all the included patterns show as blank tiles in preset manager. Any tips on how to get these to show? (I have successfully loaded other patterns before by pasting in the patterns folder, so not sure why this one is not working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns are fine. They are very subtle noise and speckle patterns.

They will appear to be simply transparent patterns in the present manager. However, if you create a black (or white) layer, then apply a pattern overlays to that layer, you will see the pattern.

This is actually **exactly** how these types of patterns should be constructed. It allows the user to set any background color they desire, then apply the noise/speckle on top of that color.